# Perl: How do I write to a directory besides bin?

Tags: perl

I am trying to output a file in perl.

I open the file and output like this..

```
open(my $out, ">",  "output.html") or die "Can't open output.txt: $!";
print $out "something!";
```

Which works perfect. If I change it to this

```
open(my $out, ">",  "c:\somedirectory\output.html") or die "Can't open output.txt: $!";
print $out "something!";
```

It does run fine(I do not get the 'Can't open output.txt' message) but when I look in the directory the file I just output isn't there. If I leave it with no path the file is found in the bin.

What am I missing here? How do I get it to output another location.

Also.. I am running the .pl using this .bat file.

```
cd\

cd \xampp\perl\bin

perl "C:\somedirectory\languages.pl"

pause
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within double quotes, `\` starts an escape sequence.  Unrecognized escapes are simply ignored.

```
print "abc\tdef";
# abc     def
print "c:\somedirectory\output.html";
# c:somedirectoryoutput.html
print qq(c:\somedirectory\output.html);
# c:somedirectoryoutput.html
```

You may double up the backslashes in order to let them pass through the double quotes.

```
print "c:\\somedirectory\\output.html";
# c:\somedirectory\output.html
print qq(c:\\somedirectory\\output.html);
# c:\somedirectory\output.html
```

You may use single quotes instead of double quotes, because escape sequences are not recognized within single quotes.

```
print 'c:\somedirectory\output.html';
# c:\somedirectory\output.html
print q(c:\somedirectory\output.html);
# c:\somedirectory\output.html
```

And a final option: the Win32 and NT APIs happily treat `/` as directory separators just as well as `\`.  While it may look odd, the following will work too:

```
open(my $out, ">", "C:/somedirectory/output.html");
```

Comment: to be honest, I think backslashes look much odder

Answer (score 4):

You have to use double backslashes as directory separators for windows paths, or use simple forward slashes.

Comment: strange i don't get the 'Can't open output.txt' message. but thanks!

Comment: @ctrlShiftBryan that's because it *is* successfully opening a file, just not where you're looking for it. Given time, you'll find the trash file you accidentally created. :)